# Convert pandas data frame to nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I have a Pandas Dataframe made from csv file, I want to convert it to a Custom Nested JSON

```
    df = pd.read_csv("/content/analog.csv", sep=",")
```

Dataframe is like:

```
datetime                key1    key2    key3        col1    col2    col3    ...  col100 
2020-08-27T02:28:00Z    WECP001 27001   con0000     1001    1002    1003    ...  1005   
2020-08-27T02:28:01Z    WECP001 27001   con0000     11      22      33      ...  99
```

I want to convert this df to a nested json like:

```
[ 
    {
       "datetime":"2020-08-27T02:28:00Z"
       "key1:"WECP001"
       "key2:"27001"
       "key3":"con0000"
       "DATA":{
               "col1":1001,
               "col2":1002,
               "col3":1003, 
               ...
               "col100":1005
              }
    },
    {
       "datetime":"2020-08-27T02:28:01Z"
       "key1:"WECP001"
       "key2:"27001"
       "key3":"con0000"
       "DATA":{
               "col1":11,
               "col2":22,
               "col3":33, 
               ...
               "col100":99
              }
    }
]
```

here is the code i have tired, but i get wrong result

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['datetime','key1','key2','key3'])
j = (df.groupby(['datetime','key1','key2','key3'])[cols]
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='DATA')
       .to_json(orient='records'))
print (j)
```

output is like:

```
{
   "datetime":"2020-08-27T02:28:00Z"
   "key1:"WECP001"
   "key2:"27001"
   "key3":"con0000"
   "DATA":[{
           "col1":1001,
           "col2":1002,
           "col3":1003, 
           ...
           "col100
           }]
```

the problem with my code is The "DATA" part became a List not a Dictionary
thanks for help

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far? The thing is, we are all here to help, but we'd like to see any efforts. It looks like you'd like us to *implement* it for you...

Comment: sorry friend, as you said, i should show my work
let me append my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, :4]
df2['Data'] = df[[f'col{i}' for i in range(1, 4)]].to_dict(orient='records')
print(df2.to_json(orient='records'))
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "datetime": "2020-08-27T02:28:00Z",
    "key1": "WECP001",
    "key2": 27001,
    "key3": "con0000",
    "Data": {
      "col1": 1001,
      "col2": 1002,
      "col3": 1003
    }
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-08-27T02:28:01Z",
    "key1": "WECP001",
    "key2": 27001,
    "key3": "con0000",
    "Data": {
      "col1": 11,
      "col2": 22,
      "col3": 33
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you, i got you idea. based on your idea i tried this: `df2 = df.iloc[:, :4] `
`df2['DATA'] = df.iloc[:, 5:].to_dict(orient='records')`
`print(df2.to_json(orient='records'))`  and i get my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("***abc.csv", sep=",")

df2 = df.iloc[:, :4]
df2['DATA'] = df.iloc[:, 5:].to_dict(orient='records')

print(df2.to_json(orient='records', lines=True))
```

result:

```
{
   "datetime":"2020-08-27T02:28:00Z"
   "key1:"WECP001"
   "key2:"27001"
   "key3":"con0000"
   "DATA":{
           "col1":1001,
           "col2":1002,
           "col3":1003, 
           ...
           "col100": 
           }
}
{....}
{....}
```